# Subfield of finitely generated field over $k$

Tags: field-theory

Let $k$ be a field. Let $k(x_{1}, x_{2},...,x_{n})$ be a finitely generated field over $k$. Where $x_{1}, x_{2},...,x_{n}$ are transcendental over $k$. Let $F$ is a field which is in between $k \subset F \subset k(x_{1}, x_{2},...,x_{n})$. Is $F$ always finitely generated over $k$ or not? If finitely generated then can we say there exist $y_{1}, y_{2},...,y_{m}$ in $k(x_{1}, x_{2},...,x_{n})$ such that $F= k(y_{1}, y_{2},...,y_{m})$. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are subfields of $k(t_1,t_2,t_3)$ which are not purely trascendental. This is part of the negative solution of the so-called Lüroth problem which is, more or less, precisely your last question.

Comment: @ Mariano thanks. Is that mean we can have $F$ which is not purely transcendental over $k$ and $F$ may be infinitely generated. I am just wandering, is that Lüroth theorem works if transcendental degree over $k$ is bigger than one.

Comment: Subfields of $k(x_1,\dots,x_n)$ are always finitely generated.

Comment: Precisely: the Lüroth problem is the question «does the Lüroth theorem work for higher trascendence degree?» and the answer is no.

Comment: @ Mariano, thank you very much.

Comment: Is it possible or not $k[y_{1},y_{2},...,y_{m}] \subseteq k[x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n}]$?